# How to get variables from a derived class into an inherited class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently developing PacMan as a school project. I have a base class called ghosts that finds the shortest path from the ghost to the target location. I also have classes such as red ghost which inherit it, these will give the base class a target and the current location of the ghost as well. When I use the red ghost it works... the variables are changed in the base class and then can be used, but for any of the other ghosts it won't work, and I can't seem to see why. Any help is appreciated :)

```
    pinkghost = new PinkGhost();
    redghost = new RedGhost();

    pinkghost.SetVariables();
    pinkghost.ChaseMode();
    redghost.SetVariables();
    redghost.ChaseMode();

public abstract class Ghosts
{
    public int ScatterX;
    public int ScatterY;
    public int TargetX;
    public int TargetY;
    public int GhostPosX;
    public int GhostPosY;
    public int StartNodeX;
    public int StartNodeY;
    public float speed = 1.0f;

    abstract public void SetVariables();
    abstract public void ChaseMode();

    public Ghosts()
    {
        //Allows ghost to access pacman coords
        PacMan = GameObject.Find("pacman");
    }


public class RedGhost : Ghosts
{
    public override void SetVariables()
    {
        GhostMov = gameobject.Find("blinky");
        ScatterX = 24;
        ScatterY = 3;
        GhostPosX = 13 + Convert.ToInt32(GhostMov.transform.position.x);
        GhostPosY = 15 - Convert.ToInt32(GhostMov.transform.position.y);
    }
}

// This one works…
class PinkGhost : Ghosts
{
    public override void SetVariables()
    {
        GhostMov = gameobject.Find("pinky");
        ScatterX = 4;
        ScatterY = 3;
        GhostPosX = 13 + Convert.ToInt32(GhostMov.transform.position.x);
        GhostPosY = 15 - Convert.ToInt32(GhostMov.transform.position.y);
    }
}
```

So as I said the red Ghost setvariables and chasemode work... but the pink ghost does not for some reason?

Comment: I have put a debug.log in and it says that the values of ghostposx and ghostposy are 21 and 23 respectively, whereas when I do debug.log in the ghosts class on the same variables it outputs 0 for both.

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but: (1) correctly invent your code, it will be easier to read. (2) put separate classes in separate files. (3) The original ghosts each had different seek behaviors (using the same technique for all four will cause them to stack up behind the player and he can evade them forever).

Comment: what does `it won't work` mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I see is that `PinkGhost` isn't public.

Comment: No that didn't work unfortunately :( all of the variables still came out as 0 instead of their actual values.

Comment: but pinkghost has another gameobject than redghost (pinky vs blinky) - which may affect the variables.

Comment: I've recently added a new comment to my post regarding this. Within the set variables class it shows the actual values that i need, whereas in the ghosts class these do not transfer across